# What is the best way to lock records for processing in Rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, locking

It's easy with simple transactions, however with complex work thats not that clear.

Let's assume we have models with some relations, for example lets take `User` and `Account`, in `Controller` we validate that `User` has enough balance and his `Account` is also valid. On that step we can query record with pessimistic locking, however it wouldn't help, because we release lock as soon as we receive data.

Those validations took some time and then we actually start doing work, querying remote API's and do complex computations, whatever.. While everything is in process we still need to hold lock on both User and Account models.

And here goes the question, what is the best way to lock records, should one add mutex in Controller to cover validation and work? Or do another validation in open transaction when models fetched again with pessimistic locking? Or maybe theres another way I missed?

Pseudo Code

#### index_controller.rb

```
def bet
  bet = Bet.new bet_params

  if bet.valid?
    BetService.make_bet(bet) #do actual work, and
  end
end
```

#### bet.rb

```
class Bet
  # some code
  validate :balance # self.user.lock!.balance > X
end
```

#### bet_service.rb

```
class BetService
  def self.make_bet(bet)
    #some long work
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
       bet.user.lock!.balance -= X
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ActiveRecord transactions if I get your question right:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  # all queries in here are in a single SQL transaction
end
```

Comment: Nope you didn't, how would you use transaction if first you do validation checking user's balance in controller and then AFTER success validation you will do actual work, e.g. increasing balance? Meanwhile another thread can successfully pass validation stage and you will stuck in race condition.

Answer (score 0):

If there are long delays, I would say to use an optimistic lock. If there are no delays, then a pessimistic lock is better.

If you need to update information in a remote API with some data you validated locally, I would say to use a pessimistic lock.

Comment: I've added pseudo code, the question is how to hold lock through validation to `BetService.make_bet(bet)`

Comment: Is that "long work" transactional? I mean, can you roll it back? Does it depend on the current values of `bet`?

Comment: Yes it can be rolled back, I just want to make all validation faster, I can check balance in validation and then recheck balance with transaction lock, however it makes two sql queries, I want to minimize it.

Comment: I'd say that, if the chances of the `bet` of being modified during the transaction are high, then you better go with pessimistic locking, as you will be doing a lot of rework afterwards. If the chances are low, and rolling back is not that costly, then do optimistic, do you API call, and then validate again and roll back if you need. In this case, 2 queries (as there are no locks) instead of one should not make a big difference in resource utilization.